# How do I install multiple versions of NodeJS without root privileges?

Tags: node.js, installation

How can I install NodeJS, not at the OS level, but without sudo privileges inside my home dir?

The thing is, I need to test my library with [at least] three versions of NodeJS:

- 10.x LTS
- 12.x LTS
- 14.x

I wanted to install them in separate directories such as:

- `~/apps/nodejs-10`
- `~/apps/nodejs-12`
- `~/apps/nodejs-14`

And then just use a symlink to switch between them if I need to (for example for version 12):

```
$ ls -s ~/apps/nodejs-12 ~/apps/nodejs_home
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to perform the non-root installation. To do this I downloaded the NodeJS packages from https://nodejs.org/download/release. Specifically:

- https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.9.0/node-v10.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
- https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
- https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.2.0/node-v14.2.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

Then, it's a matter of decompress them:

```
$ mdkir apps && cd apps
$ tar -xJf node-v10.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
$ tar -xJf node-v12.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
$ tar -xJf node-v14.2.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
$ ln -s node-v12.16.3-linux-x64 node
```

And finally adding it to the PATH, as in:

```
$ export NODE_HOME=~/apps/node
$ export PATH=$NODE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

To check, I ran:

```
$ node --version
v12.16.3
```

To switch to a different version, it's easy as to change the symlink (without touching your environment or PATH). For version 10:

```
$ rm apps/node && ln -s node-v10.19.0-linux-x64 apps/node
$ node --version
v10.19.0
```

or for version 14:

```
$ rm apps/node && ln -s node-v14.2.0-linux-x64 apps/node
$ node --version
v14.2.0
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: Did this actually turn out to work fairly well?

Comment: I received this while taring : 
tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives

this tar command worked:
tar -xvf node-v20.11.1-linux-x64.tar.x