# npm won't work after updating npm because of old nodejs version

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I couldn't do an update on nodejs to solve this, because i'm not root user on my server.

is there a way to restore npm version, without using the npm command on terminal?
(since nodejs is too old for the "new" npm to work it)

Answer (score 0):

This link is related, maybe it can fix your problem :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-node-js-and-npm-to-next-version/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-npm/

https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

Comment: thank you but none of these will work. anything with sudo is out of the question, since i'm not root. I mistakenly updated npm and now the old node version won't let me run the new npm, because it's too old. I should have update the node first, but i didn't know better.

Comment: Are you use Linux or?

Comment: This link related without root user : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754025/how-do-i-install-multiple-versions-of-nodejs-without-root-privileges  and  https://www.digizol.com/2017/08/nodejs-install-no-root-sudo-permission-linux-centos.html

Comment: I haven't got that to work yet. didn't recognize that install.. thank you, I'll keep experimenting